# The pattern order issue in NLP spaCy matcher in Python

Tags: python, nlp, matcher

I try to extract some keywords, but I am not sure what the sentence structure is.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)

patterns = [{"LOWER": "cat"}, {"OP": "?"},  {"OP": "?"}, {"OP": "?"}, {"LOWER": "cute"}]
    
matcher.add("CAT", None, patterns)
    
doc = nlp(u"I have a white cat. It is cute; I have a cute cat. It is white")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'CategoryID'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        print(rule_id, span.text)

#Output
CAT cat. It is cute
```

This pattern only displays the result with the order cat -> cute, but no cute -> cat. How can I change it to reflect both directions since I am not sure what the sentence looks like? Or Do I need to create another pattern to capture the other direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `IN` attribute or `ISSUBSET` attribute.

Instead of mapping to a single value, you can use these attributes to match the dictionary of properties.

Take a look at [Extended Patterns](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes-extended) maybe you can use ISSUBSET too, depending on your use case

**Code:**

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)

patterns = [{"LOWER": {"IN": ["cat", "cute"]}},  {"OP": "?"},  {"OP": "?"}, {"OP": "?"}, {"LOWER": {"IN": ["cat", "cute"]}}]
    
matcher.add("CAT", None, patterns)
    
doc = nlp(u"I have a white cat. It is cute; I have a cute cat. It is white")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'CategoryID'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        print(rule_id, span.text)
```

**Output**

```
CAT cat. It is cute
CAT cute cat
```